# Preserve letter casing when parsing an URL using Flurl?

Tags: flurl

Is there a way to preserve letter casing with Flurl's URL parsing?
Currently it would lowercase Host.

Input: `var url = Url.Parse("https://SomeThing.com/Path")`

Output using `url.ToString()`

Actual: `https://something.com/Path`

Expected: `https://SomeThing.com/Path`

Edited: adds sample, only Host is affected, typo

Comment: Please improve your post by including your specific use case.